# Hide Columns in Formula

Tags: hidden

I'm using SharePoint 365 on-line for about 2 weeks and i know how it works but i have a problem.

I'm using Issue Tracking App and make a list with questions to ask for a "Task" and i have 3 list views. Is it possible to hide columns from that formular. The listview is for all tickets, for Project leaders and the third for key user. The key user should not see all columns.

I already tried to make some script, to use some script and implement, but nothing works. I try with already known possibilities for solving this issue but nothing helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle this use case. Easiest of them is using targeted webpart.

Create multiple views and add those to the page. Then target who should see which view based on the webpart properties.

Next option is using CSR (Client Side Rendering). You can use this technique to code and dynamically decide which columns to be hidden.

Another option is to use JavaScript and hide the Table Column using jQuery etc.

Comment: First of all - thank you very much, i lost the hope that this gonna work. 

Can you help me with some instructions or something.